# greasemonkey-javascript: delayed-execution (for bgColor)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, delayed-execution

this greasemonkey script..

document.getElementById("leftsidebar").style.backgroundColor="rgb(211,211,100)"

..takes no effect, because the webpage is not yet loaded completely when greasemonkey is executing this script. -What do I have to do to execute the script not until the webpage is loaded completely?

Comment: Some solutions of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/1529630) would be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Greasemonkey version 3.6 or higher, you can the `@run-at` meta key inside the metadata block:

```
// @run-at  document-idle
```

See the [documentation](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at)

Alternatively, you can use the `window.onload` callback:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // all the rest of your code that must run later comes here.
}
```